# Flutter : force text to center in a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a little problem.
I would like to force the middle text to the center in the row.

[Picure of my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjGfD.png)

Here is the code I am using :

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.close),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "Modifier le profil",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      TextButton(
                          child: Text(
                            "Enregistrer",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: d_grey_icon,
                                fontSize: 15,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {}),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this updated code. I have removed the unnecessary `Row`s from your code.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
      Icon(Icons.close),
      const SizedBox(width: 35,),
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
           "Modifier le profil",
           style: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.black,
               fontSize: 15,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
             ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text(
                  "Enregistrer",
                  style: TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                   ),
                onPressed: () {})
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: I tried all the solutions.
I have now different ways to do it.

I'm new here so  I can't put a like for everyone. 
But thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

if you want absolute center you should use `Stack` instead of `Row`, for `Row` you have to give every child the same width to make it center

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you provide an example of how this works?

Answer (score 1):

like this...

```
return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Icon(Icons.close),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Text(
            "Modifier le profil",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: TextButton(
              child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
               child: TextButton(
                child: Text(
                  "Enregistrer",                
                 ),
                 onPressed: () {}),
               ),
         ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Spacer Widget in combination with the Expanded widget, try to start from this piece of code to tinker it with the expanded widget.

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Icon(Icons.close),
      Spacer(),
      Text(
        "Modifier le profil",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      ),
      Spacer(),
      TextButton(
          child: Text(
            "Enregistrer",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: d_grey_icon,
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
          ),
          onPressed: () {}),
    ],
  )
```